# Is it possible to get the json response in vue.js without passing it to the view blade?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have method in my profile controller for retrieving users details.

The route looks like this:

```
Route::get('show-profile/{slug}', 'ProfileController@show')-
>name('profile.show')->where('username', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

and the method is:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $profile = User::where('username', $slug)->first();
    return response()->json([
       'profile' => $profile,
        'title'  => 'My Profile'
    ]);
    // return view('dashboard.profile-show', ['profile' => $profile, 'title' => 'My Profile',]);
}
```

My challenge is that I don't want to pass it to the view blade, instead, I want to use vue.js and get the json response.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: To use inside Vue.js you need to call this function through route using axios library.

Comment: Just use ajax with axios like @RutvijKothari suggested...

Comment: Okay. But how can I get the parameter? If it were just post or get it would have been easier, but this involves passing the user ID